# search for a specific text in excel sheet from javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to search for a specific text in excel sheet from javascript

for example in my excel sheet there are many values like 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015  i want to know the index of 2011 , where is 2011 located and if its even present in my excel sheet or not .  For that i am trying the below code , but its not working ..

```
      var Excel;
      Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
      Excel.Visible = true;
      b= Excel.Workbooks.open("C:/work/ind.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells.indexOf("2011");
      alert(b);
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the output or error?

Comment: there's not output and no error either .. if i write Cell(1,1).value it gives me the value at the 1st index but if i do this indexof, there;s no message, alert box doesnt appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the the excel API, the `Cells` property of a `Worksheet` object will give you a `Range` type object representing all the cells in the sheet. Looking at the `Range` object's methods, I don't see any "indexOf" method. Instead, it looks like you should be using the `find` method. It appears your were trying to use javascript's `indexOf` function in an inproper place.

```
b = Excel.Workbooks.open("C:/work/ind.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells.find("2011");
```

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_methods.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.cells.aspx

Comment: its working perfectly , but its done it refreshed my browser and i lost my all text boxes and other values , can i stop it to refresh ..? thanks